# Unable to exclude disabled checkboxes when using q-table select all feature

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Quasar v.2.x and not finding much online for this version.

I am using the q-table to display several paged records. I added the selection="multiple" property to enable selecting all visible rows in the table. Each row has a checkbox. I have some business rules that require displaying the data in the table but setting the checkbox to disabled so that row cannot be selected.

This is working fine for individual rows. The problem is with the select all. If I have say five rows showing, with two disabled rows, the select all selects all five rows. I have tried everything from a computed property to a watcher to remove the disabled rows but each has their own issue. Sometimes, it breaks the whole select all, other times I get an endless loop.

```
<template>
  <q-dialog v-model="showDialog" persistent>
    <q-card
      v-show="customerCodesListData && customerCodesListData.length > 0"
      style="width: 800px; max-width: 80vw"
    >
      <q-toolbar class="bg-green text-white">
        <q-icon name="mdi-account-settings" size="24px" />
        <q-toolbar-title class="text-h6 text-weight-bold"
          >Add Customer Codes -
          <span class="text-subtitle1">{{ name }}</span></q-toolbar-title
        >
        <q-btn
          flat
          round
          dense
          icon="close"
          type="reset"
          v-close-popup
          @click="closeDialog"
        />
      </q-toolbar>
      <q-card-section class="q-pa-xs">
        <q-table
          flat
          :columns="customerCodesColumns"
          :rows="customerCodesListData"
          row-key="customerCode"
          v-model:pagination="pagination"
          selection="multiple"
          v-model:selected="selectedCodes"
          :selected-rows-label="getSelectedString"
          :filter="codesFilter"
          no-data-label="No customers found for the selected company"
          table-header-class="text-white bg-green"
          table-class="text-grey-8"
          rows-per-page-label="Codes per page"
          binary-state-sort
          :rows-per-page-options="[5, 10]"
          @request="onRequest"
          ><template v-slot:top>
            <q-btn
              push
              glossy
              color="primary"
              size="md"
              no-caps
              v-if="selectedCodes.length > 0"
              >Add Selected</q-btn
            ><q-space v-if="selectedCodes.length > 0" />
            <q-btn-toggle
              v-model="selectedCompany"
              push
              glossy
              class="q-mx-md"
              color="blue-grey-1"
              text-color="blue-grey-4"
              toggle-color="green-9"
              toggle-text-color="grey-1"
              :options="[
                { label: 'Swift', value: 'Swift' },
                { label: 'TransMex', value: 'TransMex' },
              ]"
            />
            <q-space />
            <q-input
              v-model="codesFilter"
              clearable
              placeholder="Filter by customer name or code"
              debounce="600"
              style="width: 40%"
            >
              <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon name="search" />
              </template>
            </q-input>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:header-selection="scope">
            <q-checkbox v-model="scope.selected" />
          </template>

          <template #body="props">
            <q-tr
              :props="props"
              :class="[
                props.row.isAssigned ? 'bg-grey-5 text-grey-3' : 'bg-grey-0',
                !props.row.isAssigned && props.rowIndex % 2 === 1
                  ? 'bg-grey-3'
                  : 'white',
                !props.row.isAssigned && props.rowIndex % 2 === 0
                  ? 'bg-grey-0'
                  : 'white',
              ]"
            >
              <q-td key="selected" auto-width>
                <q-checkbox
                  v-model="props.selected"
                  color="primary"
                  :disable="props.row.isAssigned"
                />
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="customerName" :props="props" auto-width>
                {{ props.row.customerName }}
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="customerCode" :props="props" auto-width>
                {{ props.row.customerCode }}
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="location" :props="props">
                <div>
                  {{ props.row.streetAddress1 }}
                </div>
                <div v-if="props.row.streetAddress2.length > 0">
                  {{ props.row.streetAddress2 }}
                </div>
                <div>
                  {{ props.row.city }}, {{ props.row.state }}
                  {{ props.row.zip }}
                </div>
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="sblc" :props="props" auto-width>
                {{ formatBoolean(props.row.isShipper) }} -
                {{ formatBoolean(props.row.isBillTo) }} -
                {{ formatBoolean(props.row.isLoadAt) }} -
                {{ formatBoolean(props.row.isConsignee) }}
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="deleteFlag" :props="props" auto-width>
                <q-icon name="check" v-if="props.row.isDeleted" />
              </q-td>
              <q-td key="action" :props="props" auto-width>
                <q-btn
                  v-if="!props.row.isAssigned"
                  flat
                  round
                  icon="playlist_add"
                  :color="props.row.isAssigned ? 'grey-0' : 'primary'"
                  @click="addCustomerCodes([props.row.customerCode])"
                  ><q-tooltip
                    anchor="top middle"
                    self="bottom middle"
                    :offset="[0, 0]"
                    class="bg-blue-2 text-grey-8"
                    transition-show="scale"
                    transition-hide="scale"
                  >
                    Add Code
                  </q-tooltip></q-btn
                >
              </q-td>
            </q-tr>
          </template></q-table
        >

        <div class="text-caption q-pa-md">
          Use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select / deselect a range and
          <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to add to selection
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</template>
  
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent, ref, watch } from "vue";
import { QTableColumn, useQuasar } from "quasar";
import { ICustomerCode } from "../../interfaces/ICustomerCode";
import { API } from "src/service/config";
import axios from "axios";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "AddCustomerCodes",

  props: {
    modelValue: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    ftUserId: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const $q = useQuasar();
    const customerCodesListData = ref<ICustomerCode[]>();
    const selectedCompany = ref("Swift");
    const selectedCodes = ref([]);
    const codesFilter = ref("");

    const showDialog = computed({
      get() {
        return props.modelValue;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        emit("update:modelValue", newValue);
      },
    });

    const customerCodesColumns: QTableColumn[] = [
      {
        name: "customerName",
        required: true,
        label: "Customer",
        align: "left",
        field: (row) => row.customerName,
        format: (val) => `${val}`,
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: "customerCode",
        label: "Code",
        align: "left",
        field: "customerCode",
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: "location",
        label: "Location",
        align: "left",
        field: (row) =>
          `${row.streetAddress1}, ${row.streetAddress2}, ${row.city}, ${row.state} ${row.zip}`,
        sortable: false,
      },
      {
        name: "sblc",
        label: "S - B - L - C",
        align: "left",
        field: "sblc",
        sortable: false,
      },
      {
        name: "deleteFlag",
        label: "Deleted",
        align: "center",
        field: "isDeleted",
        sortable: false,
      },
      {
        name: "action",
        align: "center",
        label: "Add",
        field: "action",
        sortable: false,
      },
    ];

    const pagination = ref({
      sortBy: "customerName",
      descending: false,
      page: 1, // Initial page on first load.
      rowsPerPage: 5, // Initial rows to display per page.
      rowsNumber: 0, // Number of entries.
    });

    async function getCodes() {
      $q.loading.show({
        message: "Loading codes...",
        messageColor: "primary",
        spinnerColor: "primary",
        boxClass: "bg-white border-primary q-pa-lg",
      });

      const orderBy =
        pagination.value.sortBy +
        " " +
        (pagination.value.descending ? "desc" : "asc");

      try {
        await axios
          .get(`${API}/customers`, {
            params: {
              Company: selectedCompany.value,
              FtUserId: props.ftUserId,
              Page: pagination.value.page,
              Take: pagination.value.rowsPerPage,
              SearchValue: codesFilter.value,
              OrderBy: orderBy,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            pagination.value.rowsNumber = response.data.totalCount;
            customerCodesListData.value = response.data.customers;
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error trying to load codes.", error);
      } finally {
        $q.loading.hide();
      }
    }

    async function addCustomerCodes(customerCodes: [string]) {
      const notify = $q.notify({
        group: false,
        classes: "updateUserNotify",
        position: "center",
        timeout: 0,
      });

      notify({
        message: "Adding code(s)...",
        type: "warning",
        spinner: true,
      });
      // debugger;
      console.log(selectedCompany);

      try {
        await axios
          .post(`${API}/users/customerCodes`, {
            company: selectedCompany.value,
            ftUserId: props.ftUserId,
            customerCodes: customerCodes,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response) {
              console.log("added!");
              notify({
                type: "positive",
                message: "Code(s) added",
                icon: "mdi-account-plus",
                spinner: false,
                timeout: 1500,
                onDismiss: () => {
                  getCodes();
                },
              });
            } else {
              console.log("Unable to add code(s)");
              notify({
                type: "negative",
                message: "Unable to add code(s)",

                icon: "mdi-account-plus",
                spinner: false,
                timeout: 1500,
              });
            }
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding code(s)", error);
        notify({
          type: "negative",
          message: "Error adding code",
          icon: "mdi-account-plus",
          spinner: false,
          timeout: 1500,
        });
      }
    }

    function getSelectedString() {
      console.log(selectedCodes.value);
      return selectedCodes.value.length === 0
        ? ""
        : `${selectedCodes.value.length} customer code${
            selectedCodes.value.length > 1 ? "s" : ""
          } selected`;
    }

    const onRequest = (props: {
      pagination: {
        page: number;
        rowsPerPage: number;
        sortBy: string;
        descending: boolean;
      };
    }) => {
      pagination.value.page = props.pagination.page;
      pagination.value.rowsPerPage = props.pagination.rowsPerPage;
      pagination.value.sortBy = props.pagination.sortBy;
      pagination.value.descending = props.pagination.descending;
      getCodes();
    };

    function closeDialog() {
      selectedCodes.value = [];
      pagination.value.descending = false;
      customerCodesListData.value = [];
    }

    watch(showDialog, (val) => {
      if (val) {
        getCodes();
      }
    });

    watch(selectedCompany, (val) => {
      if (val) {
        selectedCodes.value = [];
        pagination.value.descending = false;
        getCodes();
      }
    });

    function formatBoolean(val: boolean) {
      if (val) {
        return "Y";
      }
      return "N";
    }

    return {
      onRequest,
      showDialog,
      closeDialog,
      customerCodesColumns,
      customerCodesListData,
      selectedCompany,
      selectedCodes,
      codesFilter,
      pagination,
      addCustomerCodes,
      formatBoolean,
      getSelectedString,
    };
  },
});
</script>
  
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.q-table tbody td:before
  background: rgba(76,175,80,0.2)
</style>

<style scoped>
kbd {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) inset;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.q-checkbox.disabled {
  opacity: 0.1 !important;
}
</style>
```